# What does enableBasicAutocompletion for Ace Editor do?

Tags: ace-editor

What does the `enableBasicAutocompletion` option for Ace editor do? I tried setting it to `true` and `false` but were not able to observe any difference.

`enableLiveAutocompletion` does show a drop down list of suggestions for me when enabled.

This is how I am setting the options:
`ace.js` and `ext-language_tools.js` are loaded.

Then:

```
    ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var editor = ace.edit('someid');

    editor.setOptions({
        maxLines: Infinity,
        minLines: 7,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    });

    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It enables opening popup with `ctrl-space` see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.4/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L175

Comment: Thanks! :) I hope the ace team will work on improving the api reference (it's a bit sparse atm).